# Select Query is not showing result exactly with WHERE condition 1=0 or 1=1

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, where-clause, sql-like

Below is my stored procedure which is executing fine with no errrors but data is not showing correctly based on parameters values.

**Ex:**

```
exec dbo.[SP_ViewAdvanceSearchDetails] 
NULL,NULL,NULL,'AP','Saudi','1','2','2','Looking',NULL
```

By default data is showing whole list even if data is not available in Table

My problem is with `WHERE clause 1=1` ( working fine with all default values but when i change parameter values data showing wrong.) and 1=0 (working fine when i pass some values)

I am getting headache and unable to know what should I have to do.

```
       DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
      SET @sql=N'SELECT        Tbl_JobSeekers.National_Id,       Tbl_JobSeekers.JobSeeker_EnglishName, Tbl_JobSeekers.JobSeeker_Arabicname, Tbl_JobSeekers.Mobile, Tbl_JobSeekers.City, 
                     Tbl_JobSeekers.Nationality, Tbl_JobSeekers.Education, Tbl_JobSeekers.Experience, Tbl_JobSeekers.Category, Tbl_JobSeekers.JobSeekerStatus, 
                     Tbl_JobSeekers.StatusEmployer, Tbl_JobSeekers.ImagePath, Tbl_JobSeekers.ResumePath, Tbl_JobSeekers.Remarks, Tbl_JobSeekers.Email, 
                     Tbl_JobSeekers.Created_Date, Tbl_City.City_Name, Tbl_Qualification.Education_Name, Tbl_Experience.Experience_Years, Tbl_Categories.Category_Name, 
                     Tbl_Employers.Employer_EnglishName
  FROM Tbl_JobSeekers INNER JOIN
                     Tbl_City ON Tbl_JobSeekers.City = Tbl_City.City_Id INNER JOIN
                     Tbl_Qualification ON Tbl_JobSeekers.Education = Tbl_Qualification.Education_Id INNER JOIN
                     Tbl_Experience ON Tbl_JobSeekers.Experience = Tbl_Experience.Experience_Id INNER JOIN
                     Tbl_Categories ON Tbl_JobSeekers.Category = Tbl_Categories.Category_Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     Tbl_Employers ON Tbl_JobSeekers.StatusEmployer = Tbl_Employers.Employer_Id WHERE (1=0) '

--set @sql = @sql + ' 1=1 OR '
if (@National_Id is NOT NULL ) set @sql = @sql + ' OR Tbl_JobSeekers.National_Id LIKE ''%' + @National_Id  + '%'' '
if (@JobSeeker_EnglishName is not NULL) set @sql = @sql + ' OR Tbl_JobSeekers.JobSeeker_EnglishName LIKE ''%' + @JobSeeker_EnglishName + '%'' '
if (@Mobile is not NULL) set @sql = @sql + ' OR Tbl_JobSeekers.Mobile LIKE ''%' + @Mobile + '%'' '
if (@City <> 'All') set @sql = @sql + ' OR Tbl_JobSeekers.City=@City  '
if (@Nationality is not NULL) set @sql = @sql + ' OR Tbl_JobSeekers.Nationality=@Nationality '
if (@Education <> 'All') set @sql = @sql + ' OR Tbl_JobSeekers.Education=@Education  '
if (@Experience <> 'All') set @sql = @sql + ' OR Tbl_JobSeekers.Experience=@Experience '
if (@Category <> 'All') set @sql = @sql + ' OR Tbl_JobSeekers.Category=@Category '
if (@JobSeekerStatus <> 'All') set @sql = @sql + ' OR Tbl_JobSeekers.JobSeekerStatus=@JobSeekerStatus '
if (@Email is not NULL) set @sql = @sql + ' OR Tbl_JobSeekers.Email LIKE ''%' + @Email + '%'' '


--PRINT @National_Id --+',' + @JobSeeker_EnglishName + ',' + @Mobile + ',' + @City + ',' + @Nationality + ',' + @Education + ',' + @Experience + ',' + @Category + ',' + @JobSeekerStatus + ',' +  @Email

PRINT @sql

 EXEC sp_executesql @sql,

 N'@National_Id nvarchar(25),@JobSeeker_EnglishName nvarchar(50), @Mobile nvarchar(25), @City varchar(10), @Nationality varchar(10), @Education varchar(10) , @Experience nvarchar(25), @Category nvarchar(25), @JobSeekerStatus nvarchar(25), @Email nvarchar(100)',
  @National_Id, @JobSeeker_EnglishName, @Mobile, @City, @Nationality, @Education, @Experience ,@Category, @JobSeekerStatus, @Email


END
```

Comment: May I know why we need where 1=1 or 1=0 to be used with OR condition?   What is the need for that?  See my suggested answer below

Answer (score 0):

How about leaving out the constants entirely?  Then, put your `where` clause together as:

```
declare @where varchar(max) = '';

if (@National_Id is NOT NULL ) 
set @where = @where + ' OR Tbl_JobSeekers.National_Id LIKE ''%' 
                    + @National_Id + '%'' '

. . .
```

Finally,

```
set @sql = @sql + (case when @where <> ''
                        then 'where ' + stuff(@where, 1, 3, '')
                        else ''
                   end);
```

Answer (score 0):

As written, once you get to

OR 1=1 OR......

the query **will** return ALL RECORDS because the (1=1) is TRUE and the rest will not matter.

Which is why you want to use some another variable to build the WHERE clause and add it afterwards

Given:

```
 DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(max)
    ,   @WHERE VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
```

then

```
-- take the WHERE 1=0 off the END of your current @SQL 
SET @SQL = '...  Tbl_Employers ON Tbl_JobSeekers.StatusEmployer = Tbl_Employers.Employer_Id ' 


-- build your @WHERE
if (@National_Id is NOT NULL ) set @WHERE = @WHERE + ' OR  Tbl_JobSeekers.National_Id LIKE ''%' + @National_Id  + '%'' '
if (@JobSeeker_EnglishName is not NULL) set @WHERE = @WHERE + ' OR Tbl_JobSeekers.JobSeeker_EnglishName LIKE ''%' + @JobSeeker_EnglishName + '%'' '
if (@Mobile is not NULL) set @WHERE = @WHERE + ' OR Tbl_JobSeekers.Mobile LIKE ''%' + @Mobile + '%'' '
if (@City <> 'All') set @WHERE = @WHERE + ' OR Tbl_JobSeekers.City=@City  '
if (@Nationality is not NULL) set @WHERE = @WHERE + ' OR Tbl_JobSeekers.Nationality=@Nationality '
if (@Education <> 'All') set @WHERE = @WHERE + ' OR Tbl_JobSeekers.Education=@Education  '
if (@Experience <> 'All') set @WHERE = @WHERE + ' OR Tbl_JobSeekers.Experience=@Experience '
if (@Category <> 'All') set @WHERE = @WHERE + ' OR Tbl_JobSeekers.Category=@Category '
if (@JobSeekerStatus <> 'All') set @WHERE = @WHERE + ' OR Tbl_JobSeekers.JobSeekerStatus=@JobSeekerStatus '
if (@Email is not NULL) set @WHERE = @WHERE + ' OR Tbl_JobSeekers.Email LIKE ''%' + @Email + '%'' '

-- conditionally add @WHERE to @SQL 
IF LEN(@WHERE) > 0 SET @SQL = @SQL + ' WHERE 1=0 ' + @WHERE;
-- note: if @WHERE is empty, there is NO WHERE clause at all
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope your `OR` statement is not required.  In the code you are using `WHERE 1=0 OR` matching some other conditions.  In any case if one of them is true `WHERE 1=0 OR <your sql condition>` it is going to return records.  The first condition will default return false and the second one needs to be true.  We do not require `where 1=0 or where 1=1` to use it with `OR` condition.  It would be okay to leave it like this

```
SET @sql=N'SELECT        Tbl_JobSeekers.National_Id,       Tbl_JobSeekers.JobSeeker_EnglishName,      Tbl_JobSeekers.JobSeeker_Arabicname, Tbl_JobSeekers.Mobile, Tbl_JobSeekers.City, 
                     Tbl_JobSeekers.Nationality, Tbl_JobSeekers.Education, Tbl_JobSeekers.Experience,   Tbl_JobSeekers.Category, Tbl_JobSeekers.JobSeekerStatus, 
                     Tbl_JobSeekers.StatusEmployer, Tbl_JobSeekers.ImagePath, Tbl_JobSeekers.ResumePath, Tbl_JobSeekers.Remarks, Tbl_JobSeekers.Email, 
                     Tbl_JobSeekers.Created_Date, Tbl_City.City_Name, Tbl_Qualification.Education_Name, Tbl_Experience.Experience_Years, Tbl_Categories.Category_Name, 
                     Tbl_Employers.Employer_EnglishName
  FROM Tbl_JobSeekers INNER JOIN
                     Tbl_City ON Tbl_JobSeekers.City = Tbl_City.City_Id INNER JOIN
                     Tbl_Qualification ON Tbl_JobSeekers.Education = Tbl_Qualification.Education_Id INNER JOIN
                     Tbl_Experience ON Tbl_JobSeekers.Experience = Tbl_Experience.Experience_Id INNER JOIN
                     Tbl_Categories ON Tbl_JobSeekers.Category = Tbl_Categories.Category_Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     Tbl_Employers ON Tbl_JobSeekers.StatusEmployer = Tbl_Employers.Employer_Id'
```

Try to execute your sp like this

```
exec dbo.[SP_ViewAdvanceSearchDetails] 'NULL','NULL','NULL','AP','Saudi','1','2','2','Looking','NULL'
```

Between, why are all the columns are of type varchar?  Is that the requirement?